# Wait for child task to really compelete

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have the following code that start as a child task to get all files in given directory and do something on theme and call the event for each file to alert parent task :

```
internal class FileFinder
{
    private readonly string _fileFormat;

    public delegate void FileFoundDelegate(string filePath);

    public event FileFoundDelegate OnFileFound;

    public FileFinder(string fileFormat)
    {
        _fileFormat = fileFormat;
    }

    public bool Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string directory)
    {
        try
        {
            if (OnFileFound == null)
                return false;

            var foundedFiles = new ThreadLocal<IEnumerable<string>>();
            try
            {
                foundedFiles.Value = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, _fileFormat, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .AsParallel();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Parallel : " + ex.Message);
            }

            foreach (var file in foundedFiles.Value)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return true;

                // Call file found event with normalized file name
                OnFileFound?.Invoke(file);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.DebugLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message);
            return false;
     }
   }
}
```

and call it using a parent task called Scatter, the scatter run 5 seprate task that FileFinder is one of theme :

```
internal class Scatter
    {
        private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;
        private readonly string _directory;
        private readonly string _fileFormat;

        private FileFinder _emailFinder;

        public Scatter(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string directory, string fileFormat)
        {
            _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
            _directory = directory;
            _fileFormat = fileFormat;
        }

        public Task Start()
        {
            try
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(StartProc,
                    TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void StartProc()
        {
            try
            {
                // Find pdf files
                _emailFinder = new FileFinder(_fileFormat);
                _emailFinder.OnFileFound += FileFound;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _emailFinder.Start(_cancellationToken, _directory),
                    TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.DebugLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

        private void FileFound(string filePath)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File Found");
        }
    }
```

finally a master task run separate scatter for each directory :

```
internal class Master
    {
        private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

        internal delegate void ParseFinish();
        public event ParseFinish OnParseFinish;

        public Master(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        }

        public bool Start(List<string> targetDirectories, string fileFormat)
        {
            try
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartProc(targetDirectories, fileFormat), _cancellationToken);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.DebugLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                    ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool StartProc(List<string> directories, string fileFormat)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Task> targetScatterList = new List<Task>();

                foreach (string dir in directories)
                {
                    var scatter = new Scatter(_cancellationToken,dir, fileFormat);

                    targetScatterList.Add(scatter.Start());
                }

                // Wait for finish all tasks & call parse finish event
                Task.WaitAll(targetScatterList.ToArray());
                OnParseFinish?.Invoke();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.DebugLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                    ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

i have master task to wait for all directories's task to finish and don't involving the application main thread .

master task call from main thread like this :

```
    List<string> directoryList = ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();

    // Create cancelation token
    _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    _cancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    // Start master task that populate new task for each target
    var masterTask= new Master(_cancellationToken);
    masterTask.OnParseFinish += ParseFinish;
    masterTask.Start(directoryList, tbFileFormat.Text);
```

I have 287,198 PDF files in sample books directors, the FileFound event called random times in different run of project (287170, 287182, 287146 and etc) and do not iterate on all founded items .

in small file list it dose not show big difference

I think the parent task goes to finish and the child immediately goes to kill .

Any idea ?

Thanks .

Comment: just for the heck of it, could you do a `Console.WriteLine(foundedFiles.Value.Length)` to make sure the enumeration itself is complete?

Comment: You start a task in your `StartProc` method and don't await it. You mention your main thread is waiting on the parent task, but your parent task isn't waiting on the child task.

Comment: @EdT that is not true - if child task was started with AttachedToParent flag, waiting on parent task will return only when all attached child tasks are finished.

Comment: Can't reproduce behavior described. For me provided code iterates over all found pdf files.

Comment: Where did you learn to do that in your exception handling? Even just doing `catch (Exception ex)` is bad enough, but to repeat it everywhere is awful coding. You're hiding bugs everywhere.

Comment: @Enigmativity It's not my finally code, i change all code to write the exception into debugger to see what happen .

Comment: @Evk It is true in this case, since the code sample given doesn't pass any `TaskCreationOptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is one of the most amazing amount of over-coding I've seen.

Here's the same code written using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main").

```
var query =
    from dir in directoryList.ToObservable()
    from file in
            Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, tbFileFormat.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    select file;

var subscription = query.Subscribe(file =>
{
    ParseFinish(file);
});
```

That's it. It's all handled using background threads. It gets rid of all of those classes and just does the job you need.

If you want to cancel half-way through, just do this:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

If you want to know when it is complete, just do this:

```
var subscription = query.Subscribe(file =>
{
    ParseFinish(file);
}, () =>
{
    /* Handle the query is finished here */
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much , but i also want to know the problem of my code.

Comment: i have several task in Scatter and FileFinder is one of theme, i want to manually control all the operations .

Comment: @MojtabaTajik - I think your problem with your existing code is the line `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartProc(targetDirectories, fileFormat), _cancellationToken)`. You're starting a new task, but you're not doing anything with the task object that is returned. Instead you're returning a `bool` immediately.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik - And what do you mean you want to "manually control all the operations"?

Comment: You are right, the problem is that line of code , if i add a Wait() at end of it all problem solved but my main thread is involved and the UI freeze until all task done , i add master task to do not involve my main thread !

Comment: @MojtabaTajik - Your code is bad. You shouldn't be mixing Tasks and Wait like that. It defeats the purpose of using tasks.